# iCarousel View in View?

Tags: ios, xcode, icarousel

I wanted to integrate "iCarousel" into my project. Here is a screenshot how i would like it:

[image]

In the black view I would like the linear carousel.
So I implemented all the things how they did it in the example.

Now I receive the following:

[image]

Which means, that the View is now on the complete Detailview. 
Maybe you can help me to fix that?

Greetings from Germany :)

Comment: You do realize those are the exact same images.

Comment: fixed - thank you..tired i guess :)

Comment: I'm not familiar with iCarousel as I'm sure is the same with a lot of others. Could you specify what you're trying to do?

Comment: My target is just to have the iCarousel in the small black UIView (which you can see in the first screenshot). But when I'm doing everything what is wrote in the tutorial the iCarousel takes the whole screen (which you can see in the second screenshot). And I don't have any idea why this happens. And there I need help

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to set clipsToBounds =  YES on the carousel view?